# Change rows into binary string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder if there is a better solution than the one I already did using SQL Server.

My table looks like this

```
RepID   ICD9_L1
----------------
1       AB
1       NJ
1       KL
2       TH
2       KL
2       EE
2       SR
3       AB
3       SR
....
95871   PY
95871   EE
95871   AB
95871   VX
```

I want to have a list of all codes and a binary string representation if it exists in for that RepID or not

So

AB  :  1 (which means it exits for RepID 1),0 (which means it does not exist for RepID 2),1 (which means it exits for RepID 3),...,1 (which means it exits for RepID 95871)

```
NJ  :  1, 0, 0, ..., 0

KL  :  1, 1, 0, ..., 0

TH :   0, 1, 0, ..., 0
```

I built it using a look but it is very very slow

```
declare @T as table (ICD9_L1 varchar(100), StrExist varchar(max))
insert into @T (ICD9_L1)
select distinct ICD9_L1 FROM Diag


declare @i int = 0
declare @x varchar(max) = ''
declare @code varchar(10)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select ICD9_L1 FROM @T  

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @code  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    
    while @i < 70000
    begin
        set @i = @i + 1

        if exists(select top 1 * FROM Diag where RepID = @i AND  ICD9_L1 = @code)
        begin
            set @x = @x + ',1'
        end
        else
        begin
            set @x = @x + ',0'
        end
    end

    update @T set StrExist = @x where ICD9_L1 = @code
    set @x = ''
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @code 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: looks like you are doing some string aggregation. Try [STRING_AGG ()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to concatenate the `0`, `1`

Use a [tally / number table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) generate a list of IDs for left join to table. You may also use recursive CTE to generate one dynamically.

The query:

```
with 
-- generate a list of IDs
numbers as
(
    select n = 1
    union all
    select n = n + 1
    from   numbers
    where  n < 70000
),
codes as
(
    select distinct code = ICD9_L1
    from   Diag
)
select c.code, 
       string_agg((case when d.RepID is not null then '1' else '0' end), ',') 
                  within group (order by n.n)
from   codes c
       cross join numbers n
       left join Diag d   on  c.code = d.ICD9_L1
                          and n.n    = d.RepID
group by c.code
```